# EF 6, MVC Model Binding - references missing on HttpPost to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have an EF6 model that contains a collection of entity references:

```
public class Report : Entity<int>
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ReportId { get; set; }

    { ... }

    public virtual ICollection<AllocationItem> AllocationItems { get; set; }
}


public class AllocationItem : Entity<int>
{
    public int ReportId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ReportId")]
    public virtual Report Report { get; set; }

    { ... }
}
```

I have my entities seeded with sample data. Using EF, retrieving a `Report` with `ReportId=1` will completely populate correctly. All entity references appear correct:

[image: Controller HttpGet returns correct data to View]

**In the View:**

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.ReportHeader.AllocationItems.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ReportHeader.AllocationItems[i].Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ReportHeader.AllocationItems[i].ReportId)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ReportHeader.AllocationItems[i].AllocationTotal)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ReportHeader.AllocationItems[i].AllocationType)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ReportHeader.AllocationItems[i].AllocationUocAmount)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ReportHeader.AllocationItems[i].SortOrder)
}
```

**Rendered HTML:**

```
<input id="ReportHeader_AllocationItems_0__Id" name="ReportHeader.AllocationItems[0].Id" type="hidden" value="25">
<input id="ReportHeader_AllocationItems_0__ReportId" name="ReportHeader.AllocationItems[0].ReportId" type="hidden" value="7">
<input id="ReportHeader_AllocationItems_0__AllocationTotal" name="ReportHeader.AllocationItems[0].AllocationTotal" type="text" value="8,310,766">
<input id="ReportHeader_AllocationItems_0__AllocationType" name="ReportHeader.AllocationItems[0].AllocationType" type="number" value="3">
<input id="ReportHeader_AllocationItems_0__AllocationUocAmount" name="ReportHeader.AllocationItems[0].AllocationUocAmount" type="text" value="7624.49">
<input id="ReportHeader_AllocationItems_0__SortOrder" name="ReportHeader.AllocationItems[0].SortOrder" type="number" value="661204592">
```

**Fiddler Capture on HttpPost to Controller:**

[image]

**Controller result after bind**

[image]

Since these entity references aren't getting bound I have referential integrity issues. Ie, when trying to perform a Save:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A referential integrity constraint
> violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'Report.ReportId' on one
> end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of
> 'AllocationItem.ReportId' on the other end.'

I shouldn't need a custom binding model for this, should I? I do see the difference in how Fiddler is showing Name attributes. For example, Fiddler is showing `ReportHeader.AllocationItems[0.ReportId]` rather than what is specified in the HTML Name attribute of `ReportHeader.AllocationItems[0].ReportId`

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong? :S

Comment: Wrong? IMHO passing entities between client and server. Project just the properties & relative data your view needs into a view model, send that to the client, then send an updated structure with the properties that can be updated back. Load entities by ID, update values, and save. Re-attaching entities and setting modified state means passing/persisting far more data than is necessary, leading to disconnect issues like this, and exposes your system to tampering data you don't intend to allow changes to. Use ViewModels.

Comment: I am using ViewModels and EntityDto. I am only passing data between the client and server that is necessary.